# How to print the binary version of a value in an LC3(using Assembly language) using a loop and a string?

Tags: arrays, assembly, lc3

I am trying to make a program which will print the binary version of any value in r0. Our teacher told us the following:

```
To print a datum in binary, first construct a character string in 
memory describing its data bits; then display the character string via 
the service routine described above. To construct the character string:

repeat 16 times {
store( datum[15] ? ‘1’ : ‘0’ ) into the next memory location
left_shift( datum )
}
```

THe problem is, how do we go about gathering each individual bit from the binary value of r0 using just assembly language of the LC3?

Comment: Have you looked at the text book for the class?

Comment: Yep, there is nothing there that will help me.